# Need to set up SSL for facebook site apps to work, any suggestions? I do not need to protect passwords or anything

Tags: facebook, ssl, openssl, facebook-apps

facebook is forcing apps to use HTTPS, i have been looking in to openSSL, but i really cannot get my head around on how to install it, i am using godaddy and it runs on a linux server, i dont think i can execute from any command line.

I need to have a valid HTTPS link, a self signed certificate it OK, but i cannot seem to get one up on GoDaddy, can i redirect all HTTPS to HTTP, would that work? via .htacess

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem Yesterday, and quickly found a way around this without having to move my application to a server with SSL.

Facebook only validates the starting URL to be https://..... however, you are not forced to use ssl from there on forward. Thus I simply created a free Heroku account (you can use any other hosting provider that supports SSL) and added a index.php file with the following code:

```
<?php
header( 'Location: http://my.app.url' );
```

When the IFrame is loaded, it will automatically redirect to your application hosted on a non-ssl server and will work without any problems.

For more information you can check out my blog post http://www.xethron.co.za/building-a-facebook-app-on-a-host-without-https-ssl-support

Comment: And any data Facebook posts to your app in the `signed_request` parameter is lost … well, if one doesn’t need it anyway, your “solution” might be enough, but otherwise …

Comment: True. However, a simple JS redirect should fix this. Might not be ideal as users without JS might have to click a button first to submit the post, but for development purposes this could be perfect.

Comment: Actually, that will throw a warning as you will be posting from https to http. So yeah, that won't be ideal for any live running version. But still most people just need something to bypass https in the development phase...